# Webpack 5 compiles an emty bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I use webpack 5. I try to compile some files and add in to html manualy.

What I thought is that it is due to tree shaking
But when I use a function nothing happens

I create a common.js. Compile it and the production outcomes like this !function(){"use strict"}();

The bundle file is empty

my webpack config

```
const src = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

require('dotenv').config().parsed;
const env = process.env

const config = {
  target: ["web", "es5"],

  entry: {
    common: path.resolve(src, 'common.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist"),
    filename: '[name].js',
    asyncChunks: true,
    clean: true,
  },

  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: "all",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 4000,
    hot: true,
    watchFiles: {
      paths: ['public/src/**/*.*'],
    },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
    ),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.SU_EMAIL': JSON.stringify(env.SU_EMAIL)
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {},
          },
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  console.log('mode:', argv.mode)
  if (argv.mode ==='production') {
    config.devtool = "nosources-source-map"
  } else {
    config.devtool = "source-map"
  }
  return config;
};
```

`common.js` file:

```js
import './common.scss'
import './Admin/admin.scss'

const debounce = (fn, time = 700) => {
  let timeout;
  return function () {
    const functionCall = () => fn.apply(this, arguments);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, time);
  }
}

function IsJson(str) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(str);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function replaceNbsps(str) {
  var re = new RegExp('&nbsp;?', "g");
  return str.replace(re, " ");
}

function replaceNs(str) {
  var re = new RegExp('\\n?', "g");
  return str.replace(re, "");
}

function replaceTs(str) {
  var re = new RegExp('\\t?', "g");
  return str.replace(re, "");
}

function replaceSpace(str) {
  var re = new RegExp('\s', "g");
  return str.replace(re, "");
}
function replaceBackSpace(str) {
  return str.trim();
}


function trimStr(str) {
  str = replaceNbsps(str)
  str = replaceNs(str)
  str = replaceTs(str)
  str = replaceSpace(str)
  str = replaceBackSpace(str)
  return str
}

export {trimStr,debounce,IsJson}
```

Comment: How are you going to use the bundle.js file? What output did you expect?